# Did Allah know that, in the future, my friend was going to struggle for her past sins?

Tags: allah, sin, tawba, qadar

My friend recently told me a thought just came to her mind, of a sin she committed three years ago and is now haunting her. That's all she thinks about. She said at the time, she barely turned to Allah for help nor did it worry me, but now all she thinks about is that. She is always crying, asking for forgiveness hoping Aallah will forgive her. she told me that ever since this thought came to her, she turns to Allah way more, and prays and tries her best to read the Quran & listen to it.

Is it possible for Allah to know that at that time she committed the sin that in three years time she was going to stress about this and become a better Muslim?

Did Allah know my friend was going to struggle and beg for help in the future at the time she committed the sin?

Answer (score 3):

Your main question seems to be whether Allah knows the future or not, and the simple answer to that is, of course, yes He does. Allah says in the Qur'an

> [image]
>   Allah - there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer of [all] existence. Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep. To Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. Who is it that can intercede with Him except by His permission? **He knows what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, and they encompass not a thing of His knowledge except for what He wills.** His Kursi extends over the heavens and the earth, and their preservation tires Him not. And He is the Most High, the Most Great.[Surat Al-Baqarah - 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrF0H.png)

Allah knew that your friend would commit this sin and would repent in the future. However, I'm not too sure how this helps your friend out of her predicament. My advice would be  for her to continue on the path she has taken and to put all her trust in Allah. Since the "sin" hasn't come out to the public after this while, there's a very good chance that it wouldn't ever be exposed, God willing. It might be that Allah intended to use her present situation in order to draw her closer to Him. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

She should keep repenting inshallah if she is sincere allah will forgive her

Allah loves the one who sins and then repents than the one who doesn't sin at all